# Incorrect by ~100m google maps embed despite accurate lat/long

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I have an embedded google map, and am pulling the lat and long from a url saved in the db. However, the resulting map is always slightly off, usually by a few hundred meters. If I inspect the map, the lat/long are correct, but still the map is off.

Example, if I add this location: https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/China+Town+Gate/@13.7381454,100.5116292,18z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x30e29921f76193f7:0x5864886b1bdc3702!2sYaowarat+Rd,+Krung+Thep+Maha+Nakhon,+Thailand!3b1!8m2!3d13.7413762!4d100.5080243!3m4!1s0x0:0xa90b006096d12511!8m2!3d13.7371669!4d100.513057

You can see the result here: http://prntscr.com/kx17rs
Or live here: https://achefstour.com/tour/bangkok-food-tour

As you can see, the lat/long is correct, but the icon is way off.

If anyone can shed some light over why this could be happening, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates in that URL `13.7381454,100.5116292` are the center of the map, not the location of the place.  The Google Places Service returns `13.7371669, 100.513057` for the location of "China Town Gate"

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bswgkc4j/)

> Chinatown gate Tri Mit Road, Talat Noi, Samphanthawong, Bangkok, Thailand
>   Place ID ChIJP4cGNCeZ4jARESXRlmAAC6k
>   322 Tri Mit Rd, Talat Noi, Khet Samphanthawong, Krung Thep Maha Nakhon 10100, Thailand
>   (13.7371669, 100.513057)

Comment: Hi geocodezip, thanks a lot for your answer. So is it possible to pick up the correct  coordinates from a URL? Or is there an additional step?